Span white background to fit the gray background
I am working on a forum and currently struggling with css.
I want to span the white to the edge of the gray background to the right (with some 5px/ 10px gap). Not sure how to do that. I tried several css design changes but couldn't change.

Current css:
.poll-container {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.poll-content {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

Tried several items such as changing padding: 0x etc. but to no avail.

I need your html code as well as your css code.

Thanks for the response. I fixed it using flex: auto;

Updated code: .poll-content {
background-color: #fff;
padding: 10px;
border-radius: 5px;
flex: auto;
}

Added flex: auto
.poll-content {
background-color: #fff;
padding: 10px;
border-radius: 5px;
flex: auto;
}
